# Cambiar caracteres por espacio en replace javascript

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo hacer para que cambie los caracteres **=** y **?** por un espacio sin que me de el error **NaN**

```js
str.replace(/[=?]/g, "");
```

Comment: La pregunta parece un poco confusa. ¿Cuál es el valor de `str`? ¿Por qué te da un error NaN si es una operación con cadenas y no con números? (¿o es que estás evaluando el resultado después?)

Answer (score 5):

**Ejemplo 1**

Prueba agregando el operador OR entre los 2 símbolos que estas buscando reemplazar por el caracter de espacio en blanco de este modo:

```js
let cadena = "Hola_hola#hola_hola<>hola-hola@holA"

let nueva = cadena.replace(/_|#|-|@|<>/g, " ")

console.log(nueva)
```

Considerando que:

- Usamos el flag `/g` para indicar que encuentre todas las coincidencias en la cadena de texto que sean un guión bajo o un símbolo de *gatito*
- Cada símbolo que deseamos encontrar y reemplazar va separado por el operador |

**Ejemplo 2**

Incluso podemos pasar separado por otro operador `|` otra Regex que indique que la sustitución también se llevará a cabo cuando se encuentre una coincidencia al inicio con alguna letra y en especifico con la letra `H`, aclarando que solo pasará cuando esta sea mayúscula ignorando cualquier otra:

```js
    let cadena = "Hola_hola#hola_hola<>hola-hola@holA"
    
    let nueva = cadena.replace(/_|#|-|@|<>|^[H]/g, " ")
    
    console.log(nueva)
```

**Explicación**

Si observas en el enlace que te dejo al final, podrás observar que usar `[]` implica que va a buscar un conjunto de caracteres que tu definas, uno por uno o por medio de un rango; es decir:

- 1-3
- 123

Entonces cuando tu escribes **`[=?]`** tu intención es decirle que busque la coincidencia es decir donde sea igual al símbolo de interrogación, pero en realidad lo que esta buscando es donde un elemento sea **`=`** y otro símbolo sea **`?`**

**Ejemplo final**

Observa como en el siguiente ejemplo yo le paso entre los corchetes **`[=-]`** y lo que hará es:

- Buscar donde exista el símbolo de `=`
- Buscar donde exista el símbolo de `-`

```js
    let cadena = "Hola_hola#hola_hola<>hola-hola@holA"
    
    let nueva = cadena.replace(/[=-]/g, " ")
    
    console.log(nueva)
```

Dando esta salida:

> "Hola_hola#hola_hola<>hola hola@holA"

**Y como puedes notar solo llevo a cabo la sustitución después de la quinta vez que aparece **`hola`** dejando un espacio en blanco**

**Referencias**

- [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)
- [Operadores lógicos en regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)